# How to execute oracle multiple queries in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I can't get all records including the one just inserted with the code which title is "Execute multiple queries in single Oracle command in C#". Further more I got error stating "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

I want to execute multiple oracle queries as follows:

```
con.Open();
var query ="INSERT INTO myTable ( Column1, Column2, Column3 ) VALUES('a','b','c')  SELECT * FROM myTable"
OracleCommand cmd = CreateCommand(query, connection);
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   var item = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   item = SetValue(reader, item, list);
}
```

I tried also tried with begin and end, but it didn't work.

Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

joon

Comment: You want to insert a single row and fetch the whole table at the end in a single call?

Comment: yes i want a single row and fetch the whole table ,

Comment: To read data from table I think I must use  data reader instead of  executenonquery.

Comment: I think you need to adjust the SQL query you are passing, try adding a semi-colon between statements.

Comment: @DominicCotton, Thanks but I still got error msg like "{"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"}

Comment: I would personally isolate the commands - the first is an ExecuteNonQuery, followed by an ExecuteReader.  Not sure of the value of having them together...

Comment: @DominicCotton, Thanks. I think that you recommend is the best. So I did as you said.